# Issue with TFS user management view

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

TFS user management has been changed to small purple box(link taking us to visual studio page), how do we maximize and bring back it regular view.

Apart from this users tab everything else looks okay.

How do we resolve this issue, is it normal behavior of TFS ?

[image]

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. Have you tried clearing the cache of the browser?

Comment: Yes i have tried after deleting cache and cookies from the browser and i'm seeing icons on tfs instance showing as square boxes. looks like tfs is broken how do i get this back to regular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for this issue.

The thing causing the issue is **URL SCAN** that was installed along with IIS.

it is blocking certain requests on TFS and some css(which caused change in TFS user management view)

Once after removing this from the IIS, user management view came back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Could not reproduce it with the same TFS version. Suggest you also try some more client machines to see if the issue exist, if not this should be a client side issue.

Sign out your account, use another account to login the web portal, and take a look at users page if you got same result.

Besides you could also try with some other browsers IE/Chrome/Firefox to narrow down the issue.

If this is not a client side issue, since the web portal is automatically installed and configured when you install or upgrade TFS. You could check the **Event View** on TFS server machine if there are some error message. Select a recently TFS server backup and restore it, this may do the trick.

Comment: Seeing some errors in event view

ExceptionType Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestCanceledException 
 
   Message Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestCanceledException: TF400733: The request has been canceled: Client disconnected.. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContext.CheckCanceled(Boolean throwIfShutdown) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContext.get_ServiceProvider() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContextExtensions.GetService[TService](IVssRequestContext context) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation

Comment: @santhosh The client closes the connection before the request. There's nothing more the server can do.  Are you behind the proxy or under firewall? Try to remove the proxy and disable the firewall and test again.